# Timer in real time

Tags: go

I did a function that print the remaining time in real time such has TIme remaining 9 sec
then clear the term and print next sec ect.

And while it's printing the remaining time, it ask a user input, but. It'll reset the whole term and force the user to do an input on the current sentence "Time remaining...".

I don't know if it's well explained

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan string)
    done := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        for i := 10; i > 0; i-- {
            fmt.Printf("\rTemps restant : %d secondes", i)
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
        <-done
    }()
    go func() {
        var letter string
        fmt.Scanln(&letter)
        ch <- letter
        fmt.Print(letter)
    }()
    select {
    case <-ch:
    case <-time.After(10 * time.Second):
        fmt.Println("\nFin du programme.")
    }
}
```

(If you wanna check on discord ect)

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Indeed, the question is like => How to make a timer in real time while having a user input under the time ? Such as

time remaining ..Sec

User input : 

I was told that I should use smtg like raw tty but idk

Answer (score 0):

If you run your program on a standard terminal which understands escape sequences, there are some specific escape sequences to move the cursor around.

This post (with examples in python):
https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html#cursor-navigation
seems pretty pedagogical in showing how to use them

This repo (in go):
https://github.com/tom-on-the-internet/term-snake/
and its associated video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fyf-Wh4ckDk
shows a basic way to draw things on a terminal using escape sequences -- it's a snake game -- and read input directly from the tty.

---

In your case, you probably don't need to handle the input yourself, just notice that there is an escape sequence to save the current cursor position and another one to restore it.